# Facebook long-lived access token: what if someone steals it?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

From my understanding, if a bad guy steals an oauth2 access token, then they can use that token to access users' data.
Is that still true for Facebook long-lived access token? Or, facebook token is special, and is not useful without the app secret? 
Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course that’s true; it’s pretty much like your house keys in that way.

Comment: Then I'm wondering, why FB designed the auth flow like that? Why not just provides refresh token to app, which could be used to exchange short-lived access token? It's useless to steal refresh token itself without app secret, so seems to be secure and convenient enough.

Comment: Getting a new short-lived token always require user interaction.

Comment: But, with refresh token (which seems to be standard oauth), user interaction is not needed. Also it seems to be more secure, as it's tied to app secrets, so stealing refresh token itself is useless.
Do I miss something here?

Comment: Facebook login is not fully OAuth. You need a fresh user token, you need user interaction - _at least_ something like the user visiting your app website where the JS SDK can automatically check whether they are logged in to Facebook and if so fetch a fresh access token.